# Xamarin Forms ValueConverter with Bindable Property

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-properties, ivalueconverter

I have a Xamarin project, and I am trying to get a binding on my ValueConverter.
I accomplish this in my UWP project, but in Xamarin I am getting a compilation error:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'UserData', or
>   mismatching type between value and property.

The purpose of this is that when you select an item in the ListView, the entry reads the UserValue property, when you edit the text in this entry, the content of **the item's property is updated, and this change is visible in the ListView**.

There is my code:

**MainPage.XAML:**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="Entry_NewValue" TextChanged="Entry_NewValue_TextChanged"/>

    <ListView x:Name="_ListView" ItemSelected="_ListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <local:ViewCell_Converter x:Key="ViewCell_Converter" UserData="{Binding}"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserValue, Converter={StaticResource ViewCell_Converter}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**MainPage.XAML.cs:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _ListView.ItemsSource = UserDatas();
}        

private ObservableCollection<UserData> UserDatas()
{
    return new ObservableCollection<UserData>()
    {
        new UserData() { UserName = "Name1", UserValue = 10, ValidatedByUser = true, },
        new UserData() { UserName = "Name2", UserValue = 11, ValidatedByUser = false, },
        new UserData() { UserName = "Name3", UserValue = 12, ValidatedByUser = true, },
        new UserData() { UserName = "Name4", UserValue = 13, ValidatedByUser = false, },
        new UserData() { UserName = "Name5", UserValue = 14, ValidatedByUser = true, },
    };
}

private void _ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem is UserData userData)
    {
        Entry_NewValue.Text = userData.UserValue.ToString();
    }
}

private void Entry_NewValue_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_ListView.SelectedItem is UserData userData)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(Entry_NewValue.Text, out double _double))
        {
            if(userData.UserValue != _double)
            {
                userData.UserValue = _double;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

**Methods.cs:**

```
public class UserData : Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase
{
    private bool _validatedByUser;
    public bool ValidatedByUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _validatedByUser;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _validatedByUser, value);
        }
    }

    private string _userName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return _userName;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _userName, value);
        }
    }

    private double _userValue;
    public double UserValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _userValue;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _userValue, value);
        }
    }
    }

    public class ViewCell_Converter : BindableObject, IValueConverter
    {            
    public UserData UserData
    {
        get { return (UserData)GetValue(bindableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(bindableProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty bindableProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                               nameof(UserData),
                                                               typeof(UserData),
                                                               typeof(ViewCell_Converter),
                                                               null);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (UserData != null)
        {
            if (value is double _value)
            {
                if (UserData.ValidatedByUser)
                {
                    return string.Format("{0:0.00}", _value);
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Format("{0:0.0000}", _value);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: UserData seems to be a class here and not a bindable property where is the bindable property that you created for ViewCell_Converter !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you share some code as a reply please?

Comment: The reason i think you have this error is becaue your viewcell classes property has the following name : UserData and it is same as a name of the class in the same namespace try changing your property name a little and delete bin obj and then try compiling

Comment: Sadly it not worked, and I am getting the same compilation error, but thanks for your help.

Comment: May i ask you the reason you are having this class in your grid resources?

Comment: I accomplish this in my UWP project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091682/uwp-valueconverter-with-dependencyproperty

Comment: Umm I am pretty sure your UserData should be something like this {Binding .} and not {Binding}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Resoultion (Quick example):

```
    public class ViewCell_Converter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double doubleValue)
        {
            if (value is double _value)
            {
                return string.Format("{0:0.00}", doubleValue);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You dont need more for the Valueconverter.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="Entry_NewValue" TextChanged="Entry_NewValue_TextChanged"/>

    <ListView x:Name="_ListView" ItemSelected="_ListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <local:ViewCell_Converter x:Key="ViewCell_Converter"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UserValue, Converter={StaticResource ViewCell_Converter}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```